# Apache log meaning of %T and %D

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

As per the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html), `%T` means the time taken to serve the request, in seconds. But there is no description about `%D`.

In configuration file, `%T %D` is written last (in `LogFormat`). Where in the log file, 0 is being printed in place of `%T` (always) and some numeric value >10000 in place of `%D`.

I believe that the response time must not be greater than 2-3 seconds in my case.

- So please tell me which entry belongs to response time
- Why is 0 being printed in place of `%T`?
- What is the meaning of `%D`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation you mentioned was about Apache 1.3. Lots of things have changed since then and Apache 2 has been around for quite some time. From [Apache *2.1* mod_log_config Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_log_config.html):

> %D: The time taken to serve the
>   request, in microseconds.
>
> %T: The time taken to serve the
>   request, in seconds.

Comment: @Salman, The same link i suggessted in the question

Comment: @article: no... its *2.1* instead of *1.3*.

Comment: @article: your webserver is apache 2.0 or later, right?